# Why is SQL Server Recommending I Create this Index?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2012

I have the following query:

```
Select SubId, Max(ReadTimeLocal)
From dbo.PanelWorkflow 
Where ProcessNumber IN (802,1190,1605,1620,1645,1660,1695,1790,1990,2690,2795,2990,3090,3290,3590,3790,4190,4390,4590,5000,5200,5400)
Group By SubId
```

I have the following index on the dbo.PanelWorkflow table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PanelWorkflow_ProcessNumber_Lineage] ON [dbo].[PanelWorkflow]
(
    [ProcessNumber] ASC,
    [Lineage] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [SubId],[ReadTimeLocal]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

The query plan from SSMS looks as follows:

[image]

SSMS is recommending  I create the following index (with an impact of 54.3)

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[PanelWorkflow] ([ProcessNumber])
INCLUDE ([SubId],[ReadTimeLocal])
```

Does anyone know why it's recommending I create an index that essentially exists already, and is not using the one that does exist?

There are 830 million rows in the table. Using SQL Server 2012.